# Flutter TextField TextInputFormatter wipes whole string on entering not allowed character

Tags: regex, flutter, validation, dart

So I have normal TextField, like this:

```
                TextField(
                          autofocus: true,
                          controller: _textController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                                r'^[A-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-įĴ-őŔ-žǍ-ǰǴ-ǵǸ-țȞ-ȟȤ-ȳɃɆ-ɏḀ-ẞƀ-ƓƗ-ƚƝ-ơƤ-ƥƫ-ưƲ-ƶẠ-ỿ\s*&^%0-9,.-:)(]+$')),
                          ],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.transparent),
                          maxLines: null,
                        ),
```

Everything works fine, until I write character which is not allowed into the field, then whole string vanishes. I dig into it and find out that `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow` has property which is called `replacementString` which is by default as empty string. Now the question is, how exactly should I work with this, since if I add a listener to text controller and monitor changes, I don't know if user deleted the text or if user entered not allowed character. Well as far as I know.

Is there some method which just prevents to enter character with RegEx, I don't want text to get deleted, I just want prevent entering the not allowed character. Is there some way of achieving this without listeners or other methods which do this sort of checking?

Comment: try to remove $ in end of RegExp, and remove also replacementString

Comment: @Fatimaayaa Well I try to remove the $, however replacementString cannot be removed, it's part of the ```FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow``` and it's there if I like it or not, just defaults on empty string.

Comment: i try to compile it without replacementString and it work oO

Comment: @Fatimaayaa could you provide code? Because I also don't have it here as you see, it's optional parameter and if it's not filled, then it defaults on empty string. I am using emulator, so maybe the emulator keyboard do some funky stuff?

Comment: @Fatimaayaa Oh I see that I copied the code, where I have the replacement string added, because I guess when you try to find out solutions. I delete that part after it also does not work. I will edit my post. Sorry.

Comment: i past it here https://dartpad.dev/cc5e07dee60d23842c5dc92135c4c22b?null_safety=true

Comment: @Fatimaayaa Well it works now, I had to re-compile it after the RegEx edit, can I ask what does the $ do in RegEx at the end? Because I feel like I am lacking heavily knowledge about RegEx...

Comment: Im not sure but it means  position just after the last character of the string

Answer (score 18):

So the solution for this is simple, the RegEx should not have $ sign at the end, I am answering this just in case someone might find this useful.

Instead of this:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                                r'^[A-zÀ\s*&^%0-9,.-:)(]+$'))
```

It needs to be like this, for proper functionality:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(
                                r'^[A-zÀ\s*&^%0-9,.-:)(]+'))
```

Comment: Lifesaver right here.  Ty!